# Wordpress Events Manager Archive Page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using the Events Manager page and I am trying to create an archive page for events by month and year like with posts. I want the archive pages' URLs to be in the https://www.example.com/events/2017/04/

This is what I have so far. My file is saved as archive-event.php. However, when I try to go to https://www.example.com/events/2017/, I get a 404.

```
$Currenturl = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$chunks = array_filter(explode('/', $Currenturl));
$archiveYear=$chunks[1];
$archiveMonth=$chunks[2];
$archiveDay=$chunks[3];

echo EM_Events::output(array('year'=>$archiveYear, 'order'=>'DESC' ));
```

Comment: I'd recommend putting a link to the plugin. Now I'm not sure which one you are using.

Comment: http://wp-events-plugin.com/

Comment: If you are using the pro I suggest asking support there.